# XML vs. Relational databases?

Tags: relational-theory, xml

I feel like this isn't the best question to ask on a programming site like this, but I haven't really found a satisfying answer online and I would really like to get a different perspective on this.

Currently, we're working on a project at school, but instead of relational databases, we are instructed to use XML databases and related technology (XQuery, XPath and the like). I find that writing the code and infrastructure is quite straightforward, but even after working with it for a while, I can't seem to wrap my head around the advantages of choosing XML databases over a relational model.

My questions, then, are:

1. Could you describe some advantages that XML databases have over relational?
2. Could you provide an example where it might be better to use an XML database over a relational one?

Comment: Perhaps the purpose is for you to learn XML technology, and thus become aware of its strengths and limitations?

Comment: @MichaelGreen actually the assignment was simply to "write a program that involves XML databases" so I guess that's as good an objective as any!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use XML when I need more flexible structure than a database table can offer.

When you have data that you do not know exactly the structure beforehand, it could be profitable to store it as XML. You can store such XML in a relational database field, as many e-learning systems do.

In fact e-learning course structure is a good example because individual courses could be quite different from each other.

So XML is somewhere between a document and a relational-table. Imagine a database table where each record would have a very different structure, that would be good use for XML.

Also XML is very good for data interchange, meanwhile files like .DBF, .XLS etc. are not so good.

Comment: I think the e learning example is really good - one question I do have is for example when you're designing a website about an learning system, doesn't the front end design depend to a large extent to a consistent database schema? How do you reconcile different records structure on the front end? And data interchange is a really good point as well - I haven't really thought about that - thanks!!

Comment: There is of course database schema in LMS, but the parts/packages that have flexible structure, like courses definitions or test results do not have relational table representation and are stored in XML. - see e.g. http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/content-packaging/. LMS is a system that can run courses that behave and appear very differently one from another. Administration of an LMS often is more bound with relational data structure, like Users, Courses etc.

Comment: What is the meaning of the last phrase? It's not very clear. Are you suggesting that MongoDB is a relational database or an alternative to relational databases?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal sorry for the late reply - I haven't quite heard of LMS before but will most certainly check it out - sounds interesting. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually I upvoted but didn't have enough reputation points - now I do though! Upvoted thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Two good discussions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545184/the-advantages-disadvantages-of-xml-compared-to-rdms) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464166/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-using-xml-based-database).

XML pros

Export and transfer

Flexible "application or data source is robust even if the data schema changes. XML enables your application to be extensible because you access the XML-formatted data by using element and attribute names instead of offsets"

RDBMS pros

Indexing

Integrity and other constraints (i.e. foreign keys)

Atomic transactions

Triggers/stored procs

Don't need to load entire db into memory before use

Summary

Can't compare XML with an RDBMS, since that are 2 complementary technologies; XML should not be considered, or regarded as a replacement for an RDMBS

comparing dbs with files

Check out [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/xml-the-angle-bracket-tax/) excellent post concerning XML.

(imagine the following as XML - the angle brackets seem
to screw up the parser)

-- Personal view

- There is very little reason to use
- XML as a data storage method

-- Personal view

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you evaluate the following:
a) how are you going to store the data: single file vs multiple files(for example by subject)
b) are you going to be doing updates on the strings or just appending(SQL will be better suited for updates but if it just reading data after a batch processing flat files might be better suited)
c) How complex are the queries that you want to implement.XML and SQL are better suited for queries that might try to address metadata (date stored, original location address, etc.) than JSON

Once you determine what you want to optimize: whether it is on adding metadata, fast updates, fast querying, ease of storage, fast retrieval of subject files, etc. then you can decide the tradeoffs with other less important goals. In this specific instance the devil is very much in the details.